# Bootstrap 4 carousel doesn't autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

EDIT : It's looking like it finally works, the problem isn't that it doesn't works apparently, it's that it doesn't autoplay, I have to click one time on left or right, and then it will works :/ How to do the autoplay so ? The "trigger.click" way is really ... awful.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="/slider1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="/slider2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="/slider3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
```

my index.html head :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100vh;">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY"             crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>TV</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-component-router/angular_1_router.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-component-router/ng_route_shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/contents.component.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/builderror/buildError.component.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/infosAno/infosAno.component.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/infosImp/infosImp.component.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/slider/slider.component.js"></script>
    <script src="/contents/slider/carousel.js"></script>

</head>
```

I'm using Angular 1.5 to make a Single Page Application.

Comment: post your source code

Comment: Yep, no source - no answers

Comment: Have you included `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: I edited my topic.

Answer (score 0):

The example run without any js file just make sure you have to include Jquery before bootstrap js file

Here is the js fiddle code that I just created.

```
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/nxtvhj5r/
```

Comment: Which js ? bootstrap.js  ? I use no js file dedicated to the carousel

Comment: No, the custom js file, where you initializes the carousel.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, so I writed this in my carousel.js, but doesn't change (for the autoplay, it's finally the real problem, and the carousel worked without this js file :/ But I suppose I will need it for the autoplay)

Comment: Update my answer and also created a jsfiddle code for you as well.

Comment: Thanks ! But it's exactly the same code I have :/ Mine works on jsfiddle too :/

Comment: I got an error for you ! 

Here the js file :

$('.carousel').carousel();

Here the console error :

TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function

Comment: Looks like the file is called, but doesn't apply :/ (First, autoplay doesn't works, but the new interval neither :/

Comment: You need to remove data-ride="carousel"

Comment: Doesn't change anything :/